# Extract comments from any website (Comments in the .js file ) in python3 using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, python, phantomjs

I want to extract comments from the link (WebCrawler) .
This code is from [this](https://www.rt.com/usa/353493-clinton-speech-affairs-silence/) link  (Ctrl+u).

```
 <div class="spot-im-frame-inpage" data-post-id="353493"></div><script type="text/javascript">
!function(t,e,n){function a(t){var a=e.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript",a.async=!0,a.src=("https:"===e.location.protocol?"https":"http")+":"+n,(t||e.body||e.head).appendChild(a)}function o(){var t=e.getElementsByTagName("script"),n=t[t.length-1];return n.parentNode} var p=o();t.spotId="sp_6phY2k0C",t.parentElement=p,a(p)}(window.SPOTIM={},document,"//www.spot.im/launcher/bundle.js");
```

Can I go into the `bundle.js` for the extraction of comments?

I read about `phantomJs`. Can I scrape the comments from any javascript file using phantomJs in python ?(As in the above code . `bundle.js`). If yes! How? Any example of opening `.js` file?

Comment: What are comments? Do you mean the comments on the page or the comments in the code of the page? Have you tried something yourself? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service and yes, it is likely possible.

Comment: Ohh my Gosh! What the hell behavior is!

Comment: @ArtjomB. It will be fine if you give cold behavior to newbies.

Comment: Sorry if this came off a little harsh, but users are expected to describe what the problem is that you're having and letting somebody write a complete script for you is not a problem, it's a task. Hire a developer if you can't do it. If you don't want to, then you should start to learn the language and do some tutorials. There are many around. Also, you haven't answered my questions, so your question is still unclear to me. I downvoted it, because it is not a good question for this site right now and should be deleted. If you [edit] your question to make it better, I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the comments are tied to the class message-entities. I would make the crawler extract the html for each element with that class. The easiest way to use phantomJS with python is via Selenium or Ghostdriver. If you're not stuck to using python then I'd suggest using something like node-horseman or casperjs to crawl through the website and get the comments.

Comment: Can you refer me to some example of extracting comments through casperjs or node-horseman?

Comment: https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman
`var Horseman = require("node-horseman");

var horseman = new Horseman();

horseman
 .open('http://lite.yelp.com/search?find_desc=pizza&find_loc=94040&find_submit=Search')
 .text('address')
 .log()
 .close();`

Comment: How can I open any `.js` file using any above library?

Comment: Well these are headless browsers. Which means they would navigate to any site you specify in the .open() method. Then since it's in a node environment you could trigger it from your terminal using `node whatever.js`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No Sir. I am bit confuse. `nodewhatever.js` is not a file in drive. It is on the web as in the code given in the question. Can we open it and extract data from it? Any example of doing such like stuff? Openning `.js` using python3 (Horseman)?

Comment: Let me clear one thing first. Can I run `Horseman` on python3?

Comment: Crawlers are something you have to write. So say you write one that opens a website, counts the amount of comments, and then extracts the html from those comments. To run it you open up your terminal and `node nameOfCrawler`.

Comment: Like I said originally, if you're not stuck to using Python then use node-horseman. If your have to use Python, then you're better off with Selenium or Ghostdriver.

Comment: All Web Crawlers function the same way no matter if it's in a Python, JavaScript, or Ruby environment. They are all headless browsers. So you're basically simulating a user navigating a site and using javascript like methods to extract data from them.

Comment: Well. Comments on this website are not in HTML . I did not find it by ctrl+u . It is somewhere in other `.js` file. How to open the `.js` file for extracting something from it?. That is my core concern.

Comment: If it's rendered in the browser then you can get it with a scraper. You don't need to grab from the source code files. I've done this with plenty of apps that have comments and things generated with ng-repeats in Angular, so it's possible.

Comment: Anything you can use in the developer tools console to manipulate the DOM or get data, you can do in a scraper and then some.

Comment: You're crawling over the data displayed by the rendered page, not following the data in the file tree.

Comment: Can you give me any source code that extracts something from `.js` file written in Selenium or Ghostdriver?

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way. You won't consistently get the data you want if you try to get it from a `.js` file in their source code.

Comment: [Web Scraping 101](http://www.gregreda.com/2013/03/03/web-scraping-101-with-python/)

Comment: I am really stuck that how to start . It is not making any concept in me. I want to extract `javascript` data from webpage. I do not know How to do it?

Comment: The above link is using `beautifulSoup` and `lxml`. According to my understanding, we cannot extract `javascript` data from `beautifulsoup` or `lxml` . Am I right?

Comment: Well like I said in my answer the way to do it is to scrape the site with a crawler there are plenty of [libraries](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) that can do the job, you just need to pick one you like. The concept of scraping is that you use a headless browser and extract data from that rendered page. You don't mine the data from their source code. There's a lot of examples out there [this](https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/) sounds like a good resource for you to use.